# How to pass a number (through clicking Button "OnPressed property) from a stful widget (First screen on the app) to ListView.builder at Second Page

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, android-listview, statefulwidget

I got an issue. I am at the opening page of my app, which is stful widget. In the middle of the screen is a button, and a container below. In the container appears random numbers every some time. How can I solve the problem, where I want to create ListView.builder at the Second Page, which is also stful widget. I need him to be stful. I want to create ListView according to the numbers at the first page, by clicking the button and sending data to the Listview.builder.
I need a simple solution how to manage this case. All my trails failed.
It would be fantastic for a help!

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you should keep one int array and set random numbers into the array, then on the second page, you need a constructor to take data, then in init state set them. The second page should be as below example.

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<int> data;

  SecondPage(this.data);



 @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  List<int> _list = List<int>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _list = widget.data;
    super.initState();
  }
```